# How to intercept incoming call pjsip

Tags: android, pjsip

I have successfully integrated pjsip library with Android. I am also getting incoming call and make outgoing call. Only thing is, I need to make Incoming call event based. For example, when an incoming call comes, I need to first show an option to the user to pick the call up and when the button is pressed, I need to answer the call. But right now, If I put in the code to go to an activity to pick the call up, the method fails. If I call answerIncomingCall() straight away inside onIncomingCall, the call is perfectly answered by the program itself instead of Handler.post.

Can someone help me how to do this

```
@Override
        public void onIncomingCall(OnIncomingCallParam prm) {
            System.out.println("*** Incoming call....... " + prm.getCallId());

            onIncomingCallParam = prm;

            System.out.println("*** Incoming call....... 1");

            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Sip callback=>"+sipCallbacks);

                    if(sipCallbacks != null) {
                        sipCallbacks.onIncomingCall();
                    }
                }
            };

            mainHandler.post(runnable);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("*** Incoming call....... 2");

        }

        public void answerIncomingCall() {
            Call call = new MyCall(acc, onIncomingCallParam.getCallId());
            CallOpParam callOpParam = new CallOpParam();
            callOpParam.setStatusCode(pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_OK);

            try {
                call.answer(callOpParam);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: "the method fails" - what does the log say about this?

Comment: I have the issue, for iOS

Answer (score 0):

You have to answer the call inside "onIncomingCall". If you want to display a dialog for the user to accept or reject the call, you have to immediately answer the call with the code 180 (Ringing).